# How can I email large videos to someone else?

Tags: email, video, htc-droid-incredible-2

My sister took a minute long video on her new Droid Incredible 2 and wanted to share it with a friend.  The file size was about ~22 mb due to the higher quality of the recording. She's used to emailing videos with her blackberry, which produced far inferior quality videos (and much smaller sizes).  But if she tries to share this video via her gmail account, it won't attach the video because of its large file size.

Is there an easy way for her to share this video? Is there a way to shrink the size of the video on her phone by degrading the quality of video or similar?  She'd really like to just email it.

Other important information

- She doesn't want to upload the video to YouTube (or any other service)
- She doesn't have access to wifi, she uses her phone exclusively for internet access (no tethering, either).

Comment: Without using a third-party I think you're stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Best option would be to upload them to either YouTube (marked as Private or Unlisted if you don't want them searchable/viewable by others) or Dropbox. Should take the same amount of time to upload both. Once uploaded to dropbox you can share either the file or a link. I typically use YouTube as it doesn't require the other person to download the large video.

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dropbox.android

Comment: YouTube is what I suggested to her first, but she didn't seem interested in trying it.  Plus, I believe there is a limit to how big a file you can upload to YouTube without wifi (which is a real problem, she uses phone for exclusive internet access).

Comment: You could always have her chop up the video and send it in pieces: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.goseet.VidTrim A very manual process but this would serve to eliminate unecessary parts of the video and keep upload limits from being hit.

Comment: Definitely Dropbox. Don't bother uploading to YouTube and then turning the privacy on etc etc Too much trouble. Plus if you later want to delete it later it'll just be more of a pain.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience about the Droid Incredible 2, but most Android phones I've used allow to choose the quality of the recorded video from the camcorder app. Decreasing the resolution would be the only way without using hosting services.